# JavaScript passing argument via reference

Tags: javascript

let say I've got this kind of code:

```
var obj1 = {test: false};

function testCondition(condition){
  if (!condition){
    testCondition(condition);
  }
}

testCondition(obj1.test);
```

above code will pass `false` as argument to `testCondition`. How can I do to pass reference to obj1.test instead of passing it's value?

**EDIT**
wow, thanks for quick responses!! :) But I would like to add, that I cannot pass the whole object, because I would like to build one generic function/method which would just check parameter and do onComplete callback or onError callback. Above code is only example of situation where I am right now.

Comment: Why do you want to cause a recursion stack overflow?

Comment: What would you need the reference for? Do you intend to assign to the object property?

Comment: I'm developing JS application which has many async AJAX requests, by above function I would like to test if requests are finished (many parallel requests, and all kind of crazy crap. ;) ) And because of D.R.Y. I dont want to have multifunctions to check same thing, but in different conditions.

Comment: Well in async environments they *tell* you when they're finished via callbacks - no need to test for it. Or maybe you should post your actual code; this abstracted version doesn't demonstrate your problem.

Comment: no, i think it would be pointless. Anyway I think I get the picture. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two choices, from what I can see:

1. Pass the object itself, instead of its member.  You can then access and modify the member:

   ```
   function testCondition(object) {
       if (!object.test) {
           testCondition(object);
       }
   }
   testCondition(obj1)
   ```
2. Alternatively, since you're changing a single value, you can have that value be returned by the function:

   ```
   function testCondition(condition) {
       if (!condition){
           return testCondition(condition);
       }
   }
   obj1.test = testCondition(obj1.test);
   ```

FYI, your code as you've displayed it right now will cause an infinite recursion if condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with return values?

Alternatively you can wrap the argument in an object:

```
function foo(arg) {
    var val = arg.val;
    // do something with val
    arg.val = val;
}

var arg = {val:"bar"};
foo(arg);
// do something with arg.val
```

Comment: Indeed. Fixed it just now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Pass `obj1` instead, then examine `condition.test` inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. JavaScript passes objects and arrays by reference, primitives (integers, strings, booleans) by value. What you're asking for is impossible, except by bad work-arounds:

```
function ugly(result) {
  result.success = true;
}

var result = {};

ugly(result);
```

Instead, just return your value. It's how JavaScript is meant to work.

Answer (score 0):

pass the whole object instead of its property:

```
testCondition(obj1);
```

and then

```
if(!passedObj.test){
```

etc...